# Converting string to date python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I'm [following](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) the following guide on how to convert a string into a date object in python but I came across an error that I don't quite understand.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
buildDateArray.append(dt.strptime(date,"%y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

But I get the bellow error:

```
    buildDateArray.append(dt.strptime(date,"%y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2014-11-17 00:00:00' does not match format '%y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I don't understand why **'2014-11-17 00:00:00'** does not match format **'%y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'**

Can you see what the error is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format has two problems:

- `%y` matches a **two digit** year, but your year contains 4. Use `%Y` (capital `Y`) instead.
- `%b` matches a *named* month, abbreviated; use `%m` instead to match a numeric month; you need to match `11` here, not `Nov`.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2014-11-17 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 17, 0, 0)
```

When you face a problem like this, try to narrow it down to the components; you could have tried *just* the year part for example, and it'd have failed still, but with a different error giving you a big hint as to why it might be failing:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2014', '%y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 14
```

Since you are using the [`datetime.strptime()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), you need to look a the correct documentation, found at [*`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior); it details what each pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with your format

- Use a capital `Y` to match the four digit year instead of the lower case `y` (it matches only two digit)
- Use `%m` instead of `%b` to match the numeric month instead of the abbreviated month (ie. `11` vs `Nov`)

Your final format would be:

```
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```